# The output begins with space

Tags: c++, console, reverse

I made a function that will reverse the string, but the output of the reversed string always shifts towards the right by one character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void reverse(string string1)    
{
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = string1.size(); i >= 0; i--)   
    {
        cout << string1[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int main()  
{
    string string1;
    getline(cin, string1);
    reverse(string1);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first output is of a character that does not exist.

`std::string`'s leaky abstraction means that your first iteration is printing `'\0'`, which apparently looks like a space in your configuration.

**Begin at `string1.size() - 1`.**